# Fabric Archive Distribution Error:-3

Tags: google-fabric

Could not upload the distribution.The operation was not completed.（HTTP Error 400.)

[image: úi]

Answer (score 0):

The Fabric user does not have Admin (enough) rights/permission to distribute the package.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. This can also happen if the app hasn't yet been on-boarded into Fabric.